# Unable to return key of unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

The function below receives an array of names with its length, and returns the name which was repeated the most number of times. I used `unordered_map` for this purpose, but I am unable to return the key.

```
string electionWinner(string names[], int n)
{
    unordered_map<string,int> um;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (um.find(names[i]) == um.end()) {
            um.insert({names[i],1});
        }
        else{
            um[names[i]]++;   
        }
    }
    unordered_map<string,int>::iterator max = um.begin();
    for(auto it = um.begin(); it != um.end(); it++) {
        if ((*it).second > (*max).second) {
            max = it;
        }
    }
    return (max->first);   //Runtime Error Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)
    //return (*max).first; //Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)
}
```

I tried this and it worked, but can't I directly return it from `unordered_map` as its key is of type `string`?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     if (max->first == names[i]) {
         return names[i];
     }
}
```

[Driver code](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/elected-candidate/1/?track=CPP-STL-Associative-Containers-UnorderedMap&batchId=185)

Comment: Looks okay to me.  Show how you are calling this function, including how you allocate and populate the array of strings that you're passing in.

Comment: If I had to guess, `n` is likely <= 0, making `max` equal to the `end` iterator, which can't be dereferenced.

Comment: On a side note, this code can be greatly simplified. `string electionWinner(string names[], int n) { unordered_map<string,int> um; for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { um[names[i]]++; } auto it = max_element(um.begin(), um.end(), [](auto &a, auto &b){ return a.second < b.second; }); if (it != um.end()) return it->first; return ""; }`

Comment: @paddy I can't copy the driver code but I have given a link

Comment: @RemyLebeau `n` is the length of array that contains input strings.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried the lambda in lower version of c++ which doesn't support `auto` is throwing error. Have a look. [IDE](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/KVXEJ0h2DQ)
Works well in c++14 with `auto` keyword

Comment: @eras'q I'm aware that `n` is the array length. What you describe should not happen if `names` is valid and `n` is > 0

Comment: @eras'q in the lambda, you can replace `auto&` with `std::pair<const string, int>&`

Comment: @eras'q your link requires a login. Please don't link to external code. Put the relevant code directly in your post

Comment: @RemyLebeau `std::pair<const string, int>&`,This worked. Thanks.